# tikzpicture / How do I increase the vertical spacing between 2 Rectangles when the text is outside?

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, positioning, vertical

I'm trying to make a bar graph with the text above its corresponding rectangle but I'm not able to change the vertical spacing between each rectangle.

[image]

Here's the code snippet:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\RequirePackage{tikz}

\definecolor{white}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\definecolor{mainblue}{HTML}{0E5484}
\definecolor{maingray}{HTML}{B9B9B9}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\skills[1]{ 
    \renewcommand{\skills}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \foreach [count=\i] \x/\y in {#1}{
                \draw[fill=maingray,maingray] (0,\i) rectangle (6,\i+0.4);
                \draw[fill=white,mainblue](0,\i) rectangle (\y,\i+0.4);
                \node [above right] at (0,\i+0.4) {\x};
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
}

\skills {{C++ / 4}, {JavaScript, HTML, CSS / 4}, {Java / 6}}
\skills % Needed to output the text

\end{document}
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is have a for-each loop for every skill (e.g. Java) since I have more than those 3 and typing it in manually takes forever.

The problem now is that the rectangles are drawn by \draw and the node is the text.

I've tried some shenanigans with:

```
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} and \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1cm] ...
```

but that's exclusively for nodes, so not my rectangles but only the text.

The best idea would be probably to make the rectangle become a node as well, including the text, but I don't know how to do that.

If anyone knew how to add some spacing I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

I propose two solutions. In both cases, you can tune the vertical separation between skills with `\skillstretchfactor`. I prefer avoiding the `\renewcommand` inside `\newcommand` (I don't want to have to use `##` or even `####` to access macro parameters, unless in cases where this is really needed), especially redefining a macro using the same name but different semantics. In order to do this, I define a `\declareskills` macro that stores the current skills in a macro named `\skills`. This macro is later expanded by `\typesetskills` when you want to typset them.

Note: don't forget to type `C\#` for a skill such as C#, because the `#` character is special for TeX (it is used for parameter tokens and can't be input as is in text).

For the positioning of labels relatively to the “skills bars”, I use `anchor=base west` which ensures that the vertical distance from a label baseline to the corresponding skill bar doesn't depend on whether the label text contains descenders (letters like p, q or j that extend below the baseline). That wouldn't be the case with your `above right`. Also, I added `inner sep=0`, otherwise there is horizontal and vertical padding around the node text (the horizontal padding implies that the node text wouldn't be quite left-aligned with the bar—this is clearly visible on your screenshot).

## Basic solution that keeps your `rectangle` commands

This is close to your code, but has the few improvements mentioned above.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{mainblue}{HTML}{0E5484}
\definecolor{maingray}{HTML}{B9B9B9}

% Make sure no loaded package defines \skills
\newcommand{\skills}{}

\newcommand*{\declareskills}[1]{%
  \renewcommand*{\skills}{#1}%
}

\newcommand*{\skillstretchfactor}{1.2} % vertical positioning

\newcommand{\typesetskills}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach [count=\i] \name/\score in \skills {
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\vpos}{-\skillstretchfactor*\i}
      \filldraw[maingray] (0,\vpos) rectangle (6,\vpos+0.4);
      \filldraw[mainblue] (0,\vpos) rectangle (\score,\vpos+0.4);
      \node[inner sep=0, anchor=base west] at ([yshift=0.8ex]0,\vpos+0.4) {\name};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\declareskills{{C++ / 4}, {JavaScript, HTML, CSS / 4}, {Java / 6}}
\typesetskills % Print the skills diagram

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

## Solution with the `rectangle split` shape

In this second solution, each rectangle is a node of shape `rectangle split`, consisting of two parts (the first filled with `mainblue`, the second with `maingray`, as you guessed). The width and height of the skill bars can be configured with `\skillbarwidth` and `\skillbarheight`, the maximal score (corresponding to 100% of a skill bar width) with `\skillmaxscore`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\definecolor{mainblue}{HTML}{0E5484}
\definecolor{maingray}{HTML}{B9B9B9}

\newdimen\scorewidth
\newlength{\skillbarwidth}
\newlength{\skillbarheight}

% Make sure no loaded package defines \skills
\newcommand{\skills}{}

\newcommand*{\declareskills}[1]{%
  \renewcommand*{\skills}{#1}%
}

\newcommand*{\skillstretchfactor}{1.2} % vertical positioning
\setlength{\skillbarwidth}{6cm}
\setlength{\skillbarheight}{12pt}
\newcommand*{\skillmaxscore}{6}

\newcommand*{\oneskill}[3]{%
  % The 'rectangle split' (with two parts)
  \node[skillstyle={#2}] (skill-\i) at (0, -\skillstretchfactor*#3)
    {
     % Length of the score rectangle. It needs to be set globally if one wants
     % to use it after \nodepart{second} (the current group will be finished).
     \global\scorewidth=\dimexpr \skillbarwidth*(#2)/\skillmaxscore\relax
     \phantom{\rule{\scorewidth}{\skillbarheight}}%
     % Complementary width for the second part
     \nodepart{second}\kern\dimexpr\skillbarwidth - \scorewidth\relax
   };
  % The label
  \node[inner sep=0, anchor=base west] at ([yshift=0.8ex]skill-\i.north west)
    {#1};
}

\newcommand{\typesetskills}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[skillstyle/.style={
      inner sep=0,
      rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal, rectangle split parts=2,
      rectangle split ignore empty parts,
      rectangle split part fill={mainblue, maingray}
      }]

    \foreach [count=\i] \name/\score in \skills {
      \oneskill{\name}{\score}{\i}
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\declareskills{{C++ / 4}, {JavaScript, HTML, CSS / 4}, {Java / 6}}
\typesetskills % Print the skills diagram

\end{document}
```

The output is the same as in the above screenshot.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to hear that. I've simplified the code in both examples, swapped them to start with the simpler one, and added `\skillbarwidth` and `\skillbarheight` length parameters to the example that uses the `rectangle split` shape.